# Integral convergence problem

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, improper-integrals

The integral is $\int_{1}^{\infty}\sqrt{\frac{x+2}{x^4-1}}dx$.

My guess is that it does converge, since we are dividing a 1st order polynomial by a 4th order one. So it is kind of like the integral of $x^{-3/2}$ which converges with these limits. Though my intuition here might be a bit off. Anyway, I have no idea how to show this (I have tried upper and lower bounds on the polynomials, setting $x+2 \leq 3x$, etc. but it gets me nowhere).

Comment: Your intuition is not totally off, but you have to consider what happens at $1$ as well since the denominator approaches $0$ there (in other words, what happens at $\infty$ is important, but what happens at $1$ is important, too).

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this helps: $$\begin{split}
\int_1^\infty\sqrt{\frac{x+2}{x^4-1}}
&\leq\int_1^\infty\sqrt{\frac{2x+2}{x^4-1}}dx
\\&=\sqrt{2}\int_1^\infty\sqrt{\frac{x+1}{x^4-1}}dx
\\&=\sqrt{2}\int_1^\infty\sqrt{\frac{1}{(x-1)(x^2+1)}}dx
\\&\leq\sqrt{2}\int_1^\infty\sqrt{\frac{1}{(x-1)x^2}}dx
\\&=\sqrt{2}\int_1^\infty\frac{1}{x\sqrt{x-1}}dx
\\&=\pi\sqrt{2}
\end{split}$$ where the final integral is a standard one (you can verify it by making the substitution $u=\sqrt{x-1}$ which yields a standard $\arctan$ integral).